# Laravel 6.x Advanced String search locally

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I have Laravel 6.x and need an advanced search for mariaDB. I would need a search that searches all columns if they contain a specific string.

Example:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | name  | lastname     |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | peter | peterjackson |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 2  | petery| hans         |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 3  | hans  | han          |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 4  | petty | bun          |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Search querys:

`peter`: 1

`peters`: /

`pet`: 1,2,3

I tried already TNT-search but it only searches if the whole string is the same. So `pet` would only trigger at id=2.

Example for TNT-Search (Laravel Scout):

`People::search("pet")->get()`

`*no records*`

`People::search("peter")->get()`

`record id 1 (id 2 not included)`

Algolia search isn't an option because I can't outsource data into other data-centers.

Comment: your question is very unclear what you really want, please show some code where you tried to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried something like `SomeModel::where('name', 'LIKE', '%pet%')` ?

Comment: I assume you want this code to be able to search all columns on any table is that why you are trying to find something else to do what initially seems like a simple query

Comment: @WesleySmith but how do i do it, so if name isnt like "pet", but lastname is "pet" it would still be triggered?

Comment: If you want to check both columns you could use: `SomeModel::where('name', 'LIKE', '%pet%')->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%pet%')->get();` If you need to check ALL columns, let us know

Comment: @WesleySmith I need to check ALL columns, so that method would need a foreach loop. Or is there a better method?

Comment: One sec, Ill write you something that will do ALL columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested and could certainly be improved, but this should do what you want:

Add the below methods to your model, or better yet your base model which is extended by all your other models:

```
/**
 * An array containing the names of all of this model's columns
 * @var []
 */
private $_columnNames = [];

/**
 * Get an array of info for the columns of the given connection and table
 * @return array
 */
public function columnInfo()
{
    return DB::connection($this->connection)->select(DB::raw('SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM '.$this->table.';'));
}

/**
 * Get an array of all the column names for this db model
 * @return array
 */
public function getColumnNames()
{
    if (!$this->_columnNames) {
        $this->_columnNames = Arr::pluck($this->columnInfo(), 'Field');
    }
    return $this->_columnNames;
}

/**
 * Get all records where any table column is like the given value
 * @param string $value
 * @param array  $selectColumns An array of columns to return
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
 */
public static function whereAnyColumnLike($value, $selectColumns)
{
    $queryColumns = (new self)->getColumnNames();
    $selectColumns = $selectColumns ?: $queryColumns;
    $query = self::select($selectColumns);
    foreach($queryColumns as $key => $column) {
        $function = $key === 0 ? 'where' : 'orWhere';
        $query->$function($column, 'LIKE', $value);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Then you can call `SomeModel::whereAnyColumnLike('%pet%')->get();`

Comment: Thank you very much! I wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: @Gamestarplayer41 YVW, NOTE: the original post had a mistake, Ive just edited the foreach above to correct it, you'll want to do the same